# Can MySQL InnoDB corruption occur that the storage engine cannot recover from if there is NO software bug involved?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am working on an embedded Linux system running MySQL 5.1. In rare cases QA reports systems not starting properly because of mysqld not starting. If this happens the MySQL log files looks similar to this excerpt:

```
150716 14:29:42  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
150716 14:29:42  InnoDB: Starting log scan based on checkpoint at
InnoDB: log sequence number 0 133478.
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 0 133478
150716 14:29:42  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 133478
/usr/libexec/mysqld: Unknown error 130
150716 14:29:42 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run the mysql_upgrade script to create it.
150716 14:29:42 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Incorrect file format 'host'
```

This is probably due to the fact that this is an embedded device without a power switch and it is powered off by unplugging the network cable and thus killing the PoE supply. In this case of course mysqld will be terminated quite abnormaly.

my.cnf contains nothing fancy besides a size limitation to 18 MB.

**Question**

Is it possible that InnoDB tables get corrupted and **recovery is NOT possible** if there is NO bug involved (either in MySQL itself or e.g. a faulty fsync() implementation)? Are there situtations that can cause a corruption (that the DB cannot be recovered from) even if all software components are working correctly? Can such a DB be safely used in an environment where power failures occur "in normal operation"?
What I am ultimately asking is:
Is there a point searching for a fix to this problem or is there no fix to this problem whatsoever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the root cause. The problem does not actually occur with the InnoDB tables, but with the system tables.

In MySQL 5.1 system tables are stored using the MyISAM engine. This makes these tables very fragile on power loss.

For all system tables the content of the MYI (index) and MYD (data) files were lost.

Missing this data - of course - the rest of the databases had a problem...

The important hint for me was

> mysql.plugin table

Finally looked into the directory containing the system tables and saw they were using the MyISAM storage engine. Then the consequences are quite obvious.

(Only) Solution:

Go to a newer version (I used MariaDB in my case).
You **cannot** use InnoDB as storage engine for the system tables on MySQL 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that InnoDB tables get corrupted if there is NO bug involved (either in MySQL itself or e.g. a faulty fsync() implementation)?

```
Yes, eg: hardware failure
```

Are there situtations that can cause a corruption even if all software components are working correctly?

```
Yes, eg: hardware failure
```

Can such a DB be safely used in an environment where power failures occur "in normal operation"?

```
Yes, only if your hardware works "normally"
```

What I am ultimately asking is: Is there a point searching for a fix to this problem or is there no fix to this problem whatsoever?

```
Usually it's very difficult to fix the database if you meet a corruption. Do backup.
```

---

This article may help you: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-init-startup-configuration.html

Caution

InnoDB is a transaction-safe (ACID compliant) storage engine for MySQL that has commit, rollback, and crash-recovery capabilities to protect user data. However, it cannot do so if the underlying operating system or hardware does not work as advertised. Many operating systems or disk subsystems may delay or reorder write operations to improve performance. On some operating systems, the very fsync() system call that should wait until all unwritten data for a file has been flushed might actually return before the data has been flushed to stable storage. Because of this, an operating system crash or a power outage may destroy recently committed data, or in the worst case, even corrupt the database because of write operations having been reordered. If data integrity is important to you, perform some “pull-the-plug” tests before using anything in production. On OS X 10.3 and up, InnoDB uses a special fcntl() file flush method. Under Linux, it is advisable to disable the write-back cache.

On ATA/SATA disk drives, a command such hdparm -W0 /dev/hda may work to disable the write-back cache. Beware that some drives or disk controllers may be unable to disable the write-back cache.

With regard to InnoDB recovery capabilities that protect user data, InnoDB uses a file flush technique involving a structure called the doublewrite buffer, which is enabled by default (innodb_doublewrite=ON). The doublewrite buffer adds safety to recovery following a crash or power outage, and improves performance on most varieties of Unix by reducing the need for fsync() operations. It is recommended that the innodb_doublewrite option remains enabled if you are concerned with data integrity or possible failures. For additional information about the doublewrite buffer, see Section 14.9, “InnoDB Disk I/O and File Space Management”.
Caution

If reliability is a consideration for your data, do not configure InnoDB to use data files or log files on NFS volumes. Potential problems vary according to OS and version of NFS, and include such issues as lack of protection from conflicting writes, and limitations on maximum file sizes.

Comment: Do you consider power loss a hardware failure or are you referring to broken hardware only?
And my appologies my questions were imprecise. I actually meant to ask: Can corruption occur which the storage engine not automatically can recover from? I will clarify my question right away.

Comment: Possible hardware failures that cause corruptions: 1. storage broken 2. storage device with cache reports that "writing successfully" but soon power loss and the device failed to sync its cache to physical media, etc. Corruption which the storage engine cannot automatically recover from can occur.

Comment: Some more hints: we are living in a world which is full of strange bugs, so do not assume anything (you can not assume there is no bug in your db or hardware), so do necessary backup and recovery.

Comment: 100% agree. And the device has a backup and recovery function. It would be desirable though to reduce the chances of the DB being corrupted, especially in a way that requires user interaction. If this could be done by using another DB (e.g. MariaDB) or switching the flash (because it is behaving naughty). As my problem occurs seldom but regularly, I am trying to figure out, if this ususal behavior (because e.g. the InnoDB engine has been known to do so in MySQL 5.1), if something is wrong with my hardware, or if just is plain impossible to prevent these unrecoverable corruptions.

Comment: Please refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-init-startup-configuration.html , that's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgrade the MySQL version, but fail to run `mysql_upgrade` ?  That's what the error is saying.

Comment: No, I didn't do that. The error occured on an embedded system after a reboot (power being cut off before).