# How to recover from MySQL database corruption on embedded device?

Tags: mysql, database, embedded

**Setup**

- embedded device running Linux
- MySQL database stored on flash storage (using InnoDB storage engine)
- power supply via PoE or via "electrical grid"
- device has no on/off-switch like e.g. an IP phone, nobody can or will shut the system down before disconnecting power

**Problem**

- When power is lost or gets disconnected at a bad moment (i.e. when DB changes are in the middle of getting persisted), the DB might be corrupted. Often the DB can recover - sometimes it cannot.
- The flash storage is rather small, so frequently running complete backups (e.g. hourly) will wear out the storage too fast.

**Goal**

If the DB gets corrupted, I want the system to automatically recover. Having to manually restore the DB should be avoided as much as possible (but can be done as a last resort, this is already implemented).

Researching ideas I could not find much detailed information. Mostly I found advice how to prevent data loss as good as possible. I also found very general advice like duplicated data storage, error detection and correction, ...

But my problem is what to do *IF* data corruption actually occured.

**Idea**

- Replicate the DB into another DB: If the master DB gets corrupted, automatically fall back (replace it with) the replication.
- When the user logs on the next time (admin interface) show her that the DB had to be recovered and that there might be data loss (maybe with the time frame in which data was lost). Also the problem can be signaled with a status LED somehow.
- Disadvantage: More than twice the storage space is needed
- Advantage: As few as possible additional writes.

**Questions**

- Is this a valid approach or is there a major flaw in this process?
- Is there a "better practice" which I could apply? Which is that?

Comment: I really do love these anonymous downvotes without explanation on this platform! It's epic!
--- Can be answered, not just discussed. -> yes, covers software tools commonly used by programmer -> yes (MySQL), a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development -> yes (I'm developing a server and need to program a recovery strategy) ---

Comment: Wow, another downvote without reason. Pathetic.

Comment: I guess Overlords and trolls did it...

Comment: Still don't understand the downvotes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a direct answer to the question, but something that explains/removes the root cause:

The system tables of the MySQL 5.1 server are stored with - and have to be stored with - MyISAM. This makes them fragile on power failure.

Solution: migrate to a higher MySQL/MariaDB version

For more details also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34285574/3963625